# Can an upside-down USB3 header damage the motherboard?

Tags: usb, motherboard, usb-3, headers

So I bought an Asus ROG Strix X470-F Gaming motherboard, routed my cables, and realized I could do better cable management so I went to pull out the USB3 cable from the case front panel from the motherboard, and the plastic socket around the pins came out with it. And so I returned it to the store, expecting to get a new one. However, after about a week of "testing", they tell me that it boots into windows with no problems, and that the socket might fall off and this is totally normal, so after telling me it's totally normal that new products fall apart, they offered me a $50 gift card as compensation. I was thinking I'd take it and just deal with the socket being loose, but today I recieved the motherboard, and well, they put the socket on upside-down as seen in these three pictures. 
[image: here] 
[image: here] 
[image: here]

As you can also see in the last picture, they didn't put it all the way down, *and* it's not on straight. [image: Here] This is a snippet of the manual, showing the USB3 header (item 14) with the notch for the plug pointing upwards, not downwards like they put it on.

They said they tested it and that it works. But couldn't it be damaged if they tested it plugging the USB3 cable upside-down?

I can definitely fix it myself, so it's not a huge deal, really, but I'm worried about the board being damaged if they tested the USB3 port with it connected upside-down.

Comment: It's definitely not normal, but if just recently purchased it from a vendor, still have the receipt and UPC, I would see if ASUS would be willing to take the warranty return.  Assuming that the store got it through normal channels, they would also not expect the socket to just come off like that.  The store doesn't have the resources to deal with PCB repair, anyway.

Comment: Yes:  if the guard/guide is backwards that would mean they forced the USB cable to work or they reversed that connection which means a pin wouldn’t have actually been connected to the cable.  Either way it shouldn’t have worked. Please provide a clean screenshot of the both rows of pins.  It’s possible and likely probably the manual diagram is incorrect.  Sadly, you have accepted compensation from the store, so it’s unlikely you will get additional compensation unless your willing to give that up.  You should not expect to be made whole twice.

Comment: It’s possible depending on what type of header this is it’s reversible.  A clean picture will let me determine that.

Comment: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/rbdOtDN.jpg) is a photo of the pins (taken earlier, also showing the socket fallen off). As you can see, they match up with the drawing in the manual. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/X1VaHoI.png) you can also see a snippen from the manual, on a different page, showing the notch for the header pointing upwards. Also, I haven't accepted their offer yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately these plastic shrouds are kept in place by friction alone... given that some of the shrouds are slightly under-sized and some of the connectors going into them are slightly over-sized, it's possible that the friction between connector and shroud will be higher than the shroud to the pins - and the shroud will come away with the connector...

As you've already identified, the shroud should have the key oriented correctly ("*upwards*" in your case). But there is also a pin-key too:

[image: pinout]

It should be impossible to attach a compliant connector the wrong way round, even with the missing or inverted shroud, so I'd guess (if there are no bent or damaged pins) that you're fine. Note: it ***is*** possible to attach the connector off-by-one pin (or more) without the shroud.

I would also guess that their "*testing*" didn't include functional test of these USB 3.x ports - if it did, they'd discover a big problem and replace the board (i.e: the USB devices don't enumerate), or they'd realise their mistake and re-fit the shroud.

Either way, if you *were* to connect this backwards, I don't think that catastrophic failure would occur. `GND` and `Vbus` won't be swapped (potentially causing a "*short*" via protection diodes), and the signal lines should be tolerant of 5v anyway.

---

TL;DR: It's quite likely that you're fine. Re-fit the shroud the correct way and make sure it works. If it doesn't work, send it back... if it does, then keep it.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for a detailed answer! I will test this tomorrow after work and report back. The pins look fine though, so i hope you're right. *Fingers crossed...*

Comment: I wouldn't go out of your way to explicitly test fit the connector backwards... just attach it correctly, and give the two ports a test with a USB 3.x device.

Comment: I was going to pretty much submit this answer, as long as the key is orientated so you connect VBUS to VBUS and GND to GND you should be fine.  Based on the pins on the motherboard it's a standard USB 3.0 connector.  If this was a USB 3.1 Gen 1 connector it might not matter.  If you believe you can connect the cable to the pins with the keyguard/guide you should do so.  The guard/guide isn't required for it to function.  Just be sure to connect it the correct way, otherwise, you could bend the pins. (circa you can bend the pins no matter what,I speak from experience, it's difficult to do).

Comment: I thank you both for your help. Both USB3 ports on my case works just fine :)